# Unable to use Selenium in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, selenium-chromedriver

Error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class Frame1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

Code:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://google.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.close();
```

- I've downloaded all the JARs and added them all to the project from: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
  version 94 because thats my chrome version.
- I've updated Java/Ecliple/Dependencies, anything i could to make sure. (except chrome)

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with 'I've updated Java/Ecliple/Dependencies'? Do you use maven, gradle or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @pburgr None, i've just created a new "Java Project", and added "WindowBuilder".
But i have Gradle installed.

Comment: Downloading jars is simply not enough, you need to add those libs as external jars. Or use gradle https://medium.com/@milosz.wozniak/how-to-setup-selenium-java-with-gradle-minimum-dependencies-c557b19c1967, or maven https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-maven.

Comment: @pburgr i've added the JARs, just to be sure, "Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs" thats how i did it.

i'll try the gradle, thank you